# Python3 blows up code always going to try not to except

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, try-catch, except

the code works fine if I first type in some numbers, but blows up if I start with "done" - but I thought the if len(numlist) > 0 would catch that? Also the except blows up?

```
numlist = list()
while True:
    inp = input("Enter a number\n")
    try:
        value = float(inp)
        numlist.append(value)
        if inp == "done":
            break
    except:
        print("This is not a number")
        continue

if len(numlist) > 0:
    avarage = sum(numlist) / len(numlist)
    print(avarage)
else:
    print("just done")
```

Comment: Your `if inp == "done":` happens AFTER your try to float-conversion - so its never checking it because your would end up in the _excep_ part and then go merry round and never break

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you've placed if inp == "done" incorrectly. This works fine for me:

```
def main():
    numlist = []
    while True:
        inp = input("Enter a number: ")
        if inp == "done":
            break
        try:
            value = float(inp)
            numlist.append(value)
        except:
            print("This is not a number")
            continue
    if len(numlist) > 0:
        average = sum(numlist) / len(numlist)
        print(average)
    else:
        print("Just done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```